# Highcharts Solid Gauge Dynamic Update Using JSON

Tags: javascript, php, json, highcharts

Updated & Resolved, see below.

I have been working on this for several days, searching and reading many tutorials and I am still stuck.  Ultimately I am working on a page that will contain multiple solid gauge charts with data supplied by JSON from an SQLITE3 database. The database is updated every minute and I would like to have the chart data update dynamically, not by refreshing the browser page.

For the purpose of my learning, I have reduced this down to one chart.

All current and future data will be arranged as such:

**PHP**

```
[{"name":"s1_id","data":[684172]},
{"name":"s1_time","data":[1483097398000]},
{"name":"s1_probe_id","data":["28-0000071cba01"]},
{"name":"s1_temp_c","data":[22.125]},
{"name":"s1_temp_f","data":[71.825]},
{"name":"s2_id","data":[684171]},
{"name":"s2_time","data":[1483097397000]},
{"name":"s2_probe_id","data":["28-0000071d7153"]},
{"name":"s2_temp_c","data":[22.062]},
{"name":"s2_temp_f","data":[71.7116]}]
```

This is the current layout of my java:

**JS**

```
    $(function() {
    var options = {
        chart: {
            type: 'solidgauge'
        },
        title: null,
        pane: {
            center: ['50%', '90%'],
            size: '140%',
            startAngle: -90,
            endAngle: 90,
            background: {
                backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || '#EEE',
                innerRadius: '60%',
                outerRadius: '100%',
                shape: 'arc'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            enabled: false
        },
        // the value axis
        yAxis: {
            stops: [
                [0.10, '#2b908f'],//Blue
                [0.35, '#55BF3B'],//Green
                [0.65, '#DDDF0D'],//Yellow
                [0.90, '#DF5353']//Red
            ],
            lineWidth: 0,
            minorTickInterval: null,
            tickPixelInterval: 1000,
            tickWidth: 0,
            title: {
                y: -70
             },
            labels: {
                y: 16
            },
            min: 0,
            max: 1000000,
            title: {
         text: 'Degree C'
      }        
        },
        plotOptions: {
            solidgauge: {
                dataLabels: {
                    y: -10,
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    useHTML: true
                }
            }
        },
        series: []
};
    var gauge1;
    $.getJSON('sgt3.php', function(json){
    options.chart.renderTo = 'chart1';
    options.series.push(json[0]);
    gauge1 = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });
});
```

I was using information from this post but it leaves off the dynamic update aspect. As I mentioned before, I will have more charts rendering to div ids, all coming from the one JSON array, which is why I have referenced the following link:

[Multiple dynamic Highcharts on one page with json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25042030/multiple-dynamic-highcharts-on-one-page-with-json)

If anyone has an idea how to dynamically update this please let me know.  I have tried several setInterval methods but all they seem to do is redraw the chart but no data is updated.

### Update:

I spent a while doing some more iterations and resolved before coming back here. I changed each gauge to have their own function such as:

```
    $('#gauge0').highcharts(Highcharts.merge(options, {
    yAxis: {
        min: 15,
        max: 30,
        tickPositions: [15, 20, 25, 30],
        title: {
            text: 'Table'
        }
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
        data: [30],
        dataLabels: {
            y: 20,
            format: '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:48px;color:' +
                    ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black') + '">{y:.3f}</span><br/>' +
                    '<span style="font-size:12px;color:silver">Degree C</span></div>'
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: 'Tooltip 1'
        }
    }]
}));
```

Then got the setInterval to work by assigning to each gauge respectively.  I have added a lot more info than just the two I referenced but each var and setData can be added respectively.

```
    // Bring life to the dials
setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'data_temps.php',
        success: function(json) {
            var chart0 = $('#gauge0').highcharts();
            var chart1 = $('#gauge1').highcharts();

            // add the point
            chart0.series[0].setData(json[3]['data'],true);
            chart1.series[0].setData(json[8]['data'],true);
        },
         cache: false
    })
}, 1000)
```

Hopefully this can help someone in the future. This may not be the most efficient way but its working great right now. Thanks again everyone for your suggestions.

Comment: you mean, their own demo of dynamically updated gauge is not cutting it?
(http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/3.1.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/gauge-solid/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try something like this:

change:

```
var gauge1;
$.getJSON('sgt3.php', function(json){
options.chart.renderTo = 'chart1';
options.series.push(json[0]);
gauge1 = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
```

to:

```
options.chart.renderTo = 'chart1';
var gauge1 = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

$.getJSON('sgt3.php', function(json){
    gauge1.series[0].points.length = 0;
    gauge1.series[0].points.push(json[0]);
});
```

That is, updating the existing series on a chart instead of re-creating it.

As I've mentioned in the comment before, highcharts provide an example of dynamically updated gauge:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/3.1.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/gauge-solid/

Comment: Awesome thanks!  I actually just got it working using a a different method.  Refer to my updated question.